# How do I authenticate user from remote server in ajaxplorer

Tags: php, ajax, prototype, pydio

Actually for one application I am using Ajaxplorer and I have one particular domain for authenticate (i.e. www.example.com) and I am trying to authenticate user from that domain, I tried a lot to implement from the following links

- [Bridging AjaXplorer authentication with another application](http://ajaxplorer.info/documentation/developer-documentation/chapter-external-bridge/)
- [All auth plugins](http://ajaxplorer.info/plugins/auth/)

but I am unable / fail to do this. Can any body knows how to do this